# I can't create document in firestore with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use Firestore within my React Native app. So far, I couldnt reach a write/add document operation. I don't know where is the mistake? I don't recieve any error message and when I check y Firestore Database nothing is there.

This is my code:

firebaseConnection.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth }  from 'firebase/auth'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { app, db, auth };
```

signUp.js -> contains a handle SignUp function that calls the signUp function contained in auth.js

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import { Platform, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/auth';

import { Background, Container, Logo, AreaInput, Input, SubmitButton, 
SubmitText} from '../SignIn/styles';

export default function SignUp() {
  const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const { signUp, loadingAuth} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleSignUp = async () => {
      await signUp(email, password, nome);
  }
 
 return (
   <Background>
      <Container
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : ''}
      enabled
      >

        <AreaInput>
          <Input
          placeholder="Nome"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          value={nome}
          onChangeText={ (text) => setNome(text) }
          />
        </AreaInput>

        <AreaInput>
          <Input
          placeholder="Email"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={ (text) => setEmail(text) }
          />
        </AreaInput>

        <AreaInput>
          <Input
          placeholder="Senha"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={ (text) => setPassword(text) }
          secureTextEntry={true}
          />
        </AreaInput>

      <SubmitButton onPress={handleSignUp}>
        {
            loadingAuth ? (
              <ActivityIndicator size={20} color="#FFF" />
            ) : (
              <SubmitText>Cadastrar</SubmitText>
            )
        }
      </SubmitButton>

      </Container>
   </Background>
  );
}
```

auth.js -> has the definition of the signUp function. The function is creating the user in firebase , but it does not create the document and does not return any errors.

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db, auth } from '../services/firebaseConnection';

export const AuthContext = createContext({});

function AuthProvider({ children }){
    // Create new user function
    const signUp = async (email, senha, nome) => {
        const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, senha);
        const user = userCredential.user;

        await setDoc(doc(db, "user", "123a"), {
            nome: nome,
            email: email
        });

        console.log('cadastrado com sucesso');

        return user;
    };

    return(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signUp, db }}>
         {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>   
    );
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

I've tried several times and none have worked. I am very grateful if someone can help me.